# Reverse a mathematics calculation

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have a formula to do the calculation from 7 set of numbers to 4 digits, for example:

> 04, 05, 19, 21, 22, 31, 13 ====> 4382

These 7 sets of numbers are ranging from 01 to 45, each set will only exists once.

Calculation are as follow:

1. Sum up 1st to 6th number, and times with 2

   > (4 + 5 + 19 + 21 + 22 + 31) * 2 = 204
2. Take the result of step 1, minus 1st number and 6th number

   > 204 - 4 - 31 = 169
3. Take the result of step 2, plus with the 7th number

   > 169 + 13 = 182

   - From here, take the last 2 digits of the result from step 3

   > **82**
4. Sum up the 4th and 5th number

   > 21 + 22 = 43

   - From here, take the last digit of the result from step 4

   > **3**
5. Sum up the 2nd and 3rd number

   > 5 + 19 =24

   - From here, take the last digit of the result from step 5

   > **4**

There you get the final result of **4382**

If any result from any step above contains 0 (zero), take that as a value in one of the digit into the final result.

---

So anyone has any idea if I have "**4382**" with me, can you get back the 7 sets of numbers?
Not necessary must be exactly the same as I've written on top, as long as the 7 sets of numbers can produce the final result into "**4382**".

Really need a master to gimme some clues. Thanks.

1st to 6th number must be in a sequence from smallest to largest number in the range of 01 to 45. It's a game that comes out with this calculation, and I need to find out the way to reverse it.

Comment: Do you mind sharing the origin of this problem? It's very ill-posed, so I'm curious as to how it arose.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem sets out to solve the following system of modular equations:

```
x1 + 2*x2 + 2*x3 + 2*x4 + 2*x5 + x6 + x7 = A (mod 100)

x4 + x5 = B (mod 10)

x2 + x3 = C (mod 10)
```

The first equivalence comes from steps 1-3 above, the second from step 4 and the third from step 5. The basic math that you need to solve a system of equivalences is the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem).

This system will not have a unique solution. To see how redundant it is, count the possibilities for the sequence `(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7)` and `(C,B,A)` separately. For the former, `x1,x6,x7` are interchangeable as are `x4,x5` and `x2,x3`, so we count them separately. There are `(45+3-1 choose 3)` ways to choose `x1,x6,x7` each between `01` and `45` (remember to choose with repetition), and `(45+2-1 choose 2)` ways to choose each of the other pairs. This gives a total of

```
(47 choose 3)*(46 choose 2)^2 = 16 782 525
```

ways of choosing the `x`s. For the 4-digit sequence, there are `10 000` possibilities. The number above is far larger, so certainly there is a lot of repetition.

If you want to pin down just one `x` sequence that yields a given `CBA` sequence, then you can simplify the problem by choosing arbitrary values for `x6,x7,x5,x3` and then using the CRT to solve for `x1,x4,x2` (which may or may not exist).

For example, suppose you take

```
x3 = 19, x5 = 22, x6 = 31, x7 = 13
```

Then you solve for the remaining `x`s by solving this system

```
x4 + 22 = 3 (mod 10)

x2 + 19 = 4 (mod 10)

x1 + 2*x2 + 38 + 2*x4 + 44 + 31 + 13 = 82 (mod 100)
```

The first two equations are easy, though the solutions are not unique

```
x4 = 1 (mod 10) => x4 = 1, 11, 21, 31, or 41

x2 = 5 (mod 10) => x2 = 5, 15, 25, 35, or 45
```

Adding in the final equation to solve for `x1` and pin down `x2,x4` gives

```
x1 + 2*(x2 + x4) = 56 (mod 100)
```

which has many solutions, among them `x1 = 4, x2 = 5, x4 = 21`, but also `x1 = 44, x2 = 5, x4 = 1` as well as many others.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to find a solution to this would be to reverse your operations.  However, this is actually not possible with the given algorithm.  Take, for example your last step, " take the last digit of the result of the sum of the 2nd and 3rd number".  since there are multiple possible combinations of numbers that will give you this result, the step is irreversible.

If your last digit is 4 as in your example, the 2nd and 3rd number could be any of the following:

21 + 23 = 44, 23 + 21 = 24, 32 + 02 = 34, 02 + 32 = 34, etc.

What do you need this for?  Hopefully not some sort of home-baked encryption/security mechanism :)

Comment: @PengOne Not sure how this has anything to do with the Chinese Remainder Theorem, but even it is does, the question was how to get back to the 7 number sequence from the 4 digit number, which your answer does not mention.